# Why when print goes responsive layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

The problem is that. I have a website that is responsive and when i want to print that website, even on desktop it want to print the responsive version. How I can extort to print desktop version?

Comment: Print doesn't have a "desktop" size.

Comment: But website have and it print with styles for 550px

Comment: It prints with styles for `@media print`. AFAIK the print styles just so happen to look like 550px. - May you add a [mcve] in the question which also shows the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use media queries either in css or script, make sure the media type isn't `all` or doesn't include `print` if a list. Instead define separate media query for the print and define the print style inside of it.

```
@media print { 
  /* define print style here */
}

@media screen and (size selector) { 
  /* define screen style here */
}
```